# Accessing Content from MDF after attached to SQL

Tags: sql, sharepoint, mdf

I am using WSS 3.0 and trying to restore a mdf. I attached the database in SQL Management Studio, created a new web application, and associated the database to it. When I go into Central Administration-> Application Management -> Content Databases I see the WSS_Content and it says Sites: 2. One of the sites looks more similar to the other. I was able to log into the Sharepoint web app that has the db attached to it, and while it gives me the basic structure of the backed up site, the content of lists is blank, that was the data I was really after (Announcements, tasks, etc exist as lists but are empty). How do I get access to this?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove your old database and make newly added database as a default/only database for your webapplication

Answer (score 0):

I'd link to the the data from SQL Server into an Access database.. and then use MS Access to write these values back into sharepoint.

I've written a LOT of data to sharepoint using MS Access.. and I love the functionality.

Comment: Could you point me to a link that would show me how to do this? I think I'm still struggling as to WHERE this data actually is...

Comment: Interesting. Can you use an ADP and then link to the Sharepoint server? Or do you have to use an MDB/ACCDB with ODBC?

Comment: I can LINK to a Access Database that LINKS to OLE DB / SharePoint.

Comment: what you don't understand David.. Is that SQL Server _CAN_ link to anything that jet can.. and then some.

Comment: So, you cannot link directly to Sharepoint from an ADP? Is that what you're saying? That you can only get to Sharepoint via a separate SQL Server?

Comment: Aaron, I didn't ask what SQL Server could link to. I asked what data sources an ADP could be used with DIRECTLY. It is limited to connections to SQL Server, but I thought that perhaps MS had implemented the ability to link directly to Sharepoint as well, since that's SQL Server underneath.

Comment: What I understand perfectly well, Aaron, is that SQL Server can link to almost anything, but also that Jet/ACE can also link to almost anything. I also understand that an MDB/ACCDB can link to data in almost any format, but an ADP can link only to a SQL Server. I just thought that perhaps you knew more than I do in that regard, since you claim such an intense level of expertise in SQL Server. And you didn't really answer my question directly -- you answered it in an evasive fashion that suggest you were trying to hide something.

Answer (score -1):

the data is in SQL server.. but it's got different guids, or it's not wired up from what I'd assume.

You have the data posted to the SQL Server instance.. I'd just link to it in MS Access, write a couple of queries.. recreate a couple of lists.. and then push it from queries based on Access linked tables (to sql server).. and then jam it into Access linked tables (to sharepoint).

Open Access. right-click link basically.  times two. and write a couple of queries.

If it was me, and it was just a couple of lists, I'd do this in a couple of minutes I swear.